# Get values of checkboxes [Ruby/Sinatra(Rails)]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, sinatra

I have some checkboxes on one view, that I want to eval on another, but I dont understand what its doing.

I've read posts/blogs stating different approaches to the `name` :-

```
update_params[]                     # array
update_params[0], update_params[1]  # known indexed array
update_params0, update_params1      # differently named
```

So going with the first which seems the most common :-

```
# views/index.erb
<input type="checkbox" name="update_params[]" value="Copy" />Update the host<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="update_params[]" value="Start" />Start the software<br/>
```

Should the `value` be indexed? `0`, `1`?

So I want two outcomes

1) Display the options selected from the index.erb view on the version.erb view.

So that it looks something like :-

```
Copy : Yes
Start : No
```

Currently I have :-

```
# views/version.erb
<p>Copy : <%= params['update_params[0]'] %></p>
<p>Start : <%= params['update_params[1]'] %></p>
```

2) eval the options to pass to a script so that they become command line options, ie `-c`, `-l`

So my "controller"

```
# update.rb
helpers do
  def run_update(version, host, params)
    command = "./update.sh #{params} #{host}" # -c -l
    @ok = system( command )
  end
end

post '/version' do
  run_update(params[:version_list], params[:host], params[:update_params])
  erb :version
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe instead of relying on index, you could use keys in the array? For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="update_params[copy]" value="Copy" />Update the host<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="update_params[start]" value="Start" />Start the software<br/>
```

So then, you can do stuff like:

```
params[:update_params][:copy]
```